# Alcatel One Touch driver for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, drivers

I am looking for a driver that would make my Alcatel One Touch x500 modem work on Windows 8.1.

I got it to work on every OS but Win 8.1. On Windows it uses the MyConnection app to connect, but it doesnt recognize the modem on Windows 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason, on http://www.alcatelonetouch.com/global-en/products/mobile_broadband/ot-x500.html, the Windows 8 instructions (contains driver as well) seem to be posted only in Italian (grab **aggiornamento-x500e-wind-per-supporto-windows-8.rar**). Give it a try, it should work on 8.1 as well.

**[L.E. - 13/06/2016]** Above link seems to be dead, see **katalin_2003**'s contribution below for a working one.

Comment: Excellent, I've seen in the mean time topics on other forums on the same subject, unanswered, so maybe this will benefit others as well.

Comment: Any of you guys saved a copy of this file? The link is dead now. Thanks

Comment: Found it here: http://www.wind.it/fileadmin/Materiale/Mobile/Internet_Key/X500E_Wind_Windows_8_update.rar . Source: http://www.adsmcard.com/2013/10/aggiornamento-software-chiavette-internet-wind-per-windows-8/

Comment: @katalin_2003: Thank you for the updated link. I'll edit my original response to point in your direction.